# Counting itab groups without a loop

Tags: abap

I recently found out about the [GROUP BY](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abaploop_at_itab_group_by.htm) command in loops.

Now imagine following example:

I have an itab with a column `categories`. I want to know how many different categories there are.
Using the GROUP BY statement linked above I could count the number of times the loop is executed. Is there a simpler way without having to loop?

Comment: Anyway, you can imagine that the processor must iterate the lines to count the number of distinct values, so I guess your question is more about the shortest way to write it … no doubt that you should use REDUCE … FOR GROUPS … GROUP BY …, but that would help a lot if you could provide your code snippet to help answering.

Comment: Can you provide existing code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a short example code wrapped in a report you can try on your system.

```
REPORT Z_GROUP_COUNT.

  TYPES: BEGIN OF lty_st_for_reduce,
           categories TYPE C LENGTH 4,
         END OF lty_st_for_reduce.

  DATA: lt_for_reduce TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF lty_st_for_reduce.

  APPEND VALUE #( categories = 'ABAP' ) TO lt_for_reduce.
  APPEND VALUE #( categories = 'OBJC' ) TO lt_for_reduce.
  APPEND VALUE #( categories = 'ABAP' ) TO lt_for_reduce.
  APPEND VALUE #( categories = 'ABAP' ) TO lt_for_reduce.
  APPEND VALUE #( categories = 'OBJC' ) TO lt_for_reduce.

  DATA(lv_categories_count) = REDUCE i( INIT count = 0
                                        FOR GROUPS categories OF entry IN lt_for_reduce
                                        GROUP BY ( categories = entry-categories )
                                        NEXT count = count + 1 ).

  " Will output `2`.
  WRITE: lv_categories_count.
```

Comment: Looks good, I will check this as the answer once I succesfully tested it in my code :) So it seems `Reduce` was what I was looking for, I knew something like this must exist somewhere :D

Comment: I don't see any performance differences. This is a loop also, just in a fancy way. :)